# MongoDB count,min,max,avg for aggregate using field with List of objects

Tags: mongodb, statistics, aggregate

I have problem with get statistics data using MongoDB collection.

[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpsGW.png)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfca"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["I07WOS4YJ0N7YRFE7309"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "5493000U0YGG4VEQOX65"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcb"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_DIRECTLY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["529900P6OUCFPVWCFE19", "8945007IZBKFQUQLIP85"]
      },
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["529900P6OUCFPVWCFE19"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "89450012XZ2GPWGIGH37"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcc"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["815600C9588783AB0210"]
      },
      {
        "type": "IS_DIRECTLY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["815600C9588783AB0210"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "815600228127946DFF05"
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "616309f71b021c754992bfcd"},
    "correlatedNodes": [
      {
        "type": "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY",
        "nodes": ["549300LI58A0MHGHTZ98"]
      }
    ],
    "fromTaskId": 20,
    "nodeName": "549300NV4OCF16TAS048"
  }
]
```

I want to get basic statistic information for correlatedNodes field.

Something like:

```
{
  "IS_ULTIMATELY_CONSOLIDATED_BY": {
      "count": 567,
      "avg": 22,
      "min": 3,
      "max": 50
    }
}
```

By count I mean to use list size for each connection type.

I tried aggregate query like this:

```
db.node_correlations.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {"correlatedNodes":  "$correlatedNodes" },
        $unwind: "$correlatedNodes"
    }
]);
```

But I received error:

> [2021-10-13 12:14:10] com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40323 (Location40323): 'A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.", "code": 40323, "codeName": "Location40323"}

Comment: The `$project` and `$unwind` are two different stages - you have a syntax error. Refer the MongoDB Manual documentation for correct usage of these aggregation stages.

Comment: How do you get `avg`, `min` and `max`? By the way, I think you are looking for something similar to [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ph32vxErUdF) using `$unwind` and `$group`.

Comment: Can you clarify more on "list size for each connection type"? Is that group by `correlatedNodes.type` and retrieve the counts? What is the meaning of min, max and avg then?

Comment: By min,max and avg I mean to get information about minimum list size for each type in all records in collection. Same for the avg and max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for help.

Working solutions is:

```
db.node_correlations.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$correlatedNodes"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$correlatedNodes.type",
      "count": {
        "$sum": {"$size": "$correlatedNodes.nodes"}
      },
      "avg": {
        "$avg": {"$size": "$correlatedNodes.nodes"}
      },
      "min": {
        "$min": {"$size": "$correlatedNodes.nodes"}
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": {"$size": "$correlatedNodes.nodes"}
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).